# Connect Dynamics 365 Email Router On Premise to Exchange 2016 on premise

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365, email-router

we have a Dynamics 365 Version 8.2 on premise in our company and our email service is based on Microsoft Exchange 2016 on premise. I Want To Install Email Router in my crm server and Then Connect it to exchange server to send and receive email from crm but my problem is there is no any option about exchange 2016 and i have been search whole the internet and there is no any good solution. when i set incoming profile to pop3 and outgoing to smtp when i click on Test Access button it show me an error at incoming but outgoing show me a success message. please help me to handle this error.

the error is:

"Incoming Status: Failure - An error occurred while executing POP3 command "". The server response was: "220 mail.modernisc.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 3 Oct 2018 12:26:29 +0330". 
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use server side synchronisation:
[Connect Dynamics 365 (on-premises) to Exchange Server (on-premises)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622062.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @sgeis i saw this document before but i can't use that expression and then after you suggest that again to me, i use this document to configure Server Side Synchronization and every thing going well and now i can send and receive any email from CRM.